# Lambda in return statement cannot be implicitly converted to functor

Tags: c++

I have the following code

```
struct Functor
{
    Functor(std::function<void()> task) : _task {task} {}
    void operator() () {_task();}
    std::function<void()> _task{};
};

Functor run1() //OK
{
    return Functor([](){std::cout << "From function" << std::endl;});
}

Functor run2() //Bad. Compile time error
{
    return [](){std::cout << "From function" << std::endl;};
}
```

My questions are:

1. Why `run1()` is okay but `run2()` is not allowed?
2. Is there a constructor in the struct `Functor` that I can define in order to make `run2()` valid as it is? I am asking this because currently the return type of `run2()` in my project is `std::function<void()>` and all is good, but I now need to change it into a functor to store some additional properties, but return statement like `run2()` are used in many places, and I am reluctant to modify every occurrences of it into `run1()`.

Comment: Only one implicit user-conversion allowed. `run2` need 2 (lambda-> `std::function` -> `Functor`).

Comment: How about turning your `Functor` constructor into a template?  `template<class F> Functor(F&& task) : _task(std::forward<F>(task)) {}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. As it is already mentioned in the comments, `run2` requires two implicit user conversions, which is prohibited.
2. You can create a template constructor in `Functor` to make your code valid:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

struct Functor {
    Functor(auto && task) : _task { task } {}
    void operator() () {_task();}
    std::function<void()> _task{};
};

Functor run1() //OK
{
    return Functor([](){std::cout << "From function" << std::endl;});
}

Functor run2() //Ok
{
    return [](){std::cout << "From function" << std::endl;};
}
```

Demo: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/bdnYTbKv4